# providing multiple threading or task creation

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am trying to implement few files (video files) to generate their media information. I got one list view named (Details) and each files are added 3-4 times depending on their genre like this:

Action Avengers Infinity War 2.6 GB

Adventure Avengers Infinity War 2.6 GB

Sci-Fi Avengers Infinity War 2.6 GB

Action Mission Impossible Fallout 4.7 GB

Adventure Mission Impossible Fallout 4.7 GB

Thriller Mission Impossible Fallout 4.7 GB

Adventure Toy Story 1.4 GB

Comedy Toy Story 1.4 GB

I tried to implement few codes this like

```
Parallel.For(0, Details.Items.Count, i =>
                        {
                            FileName = Details.Items[i].SubItems[7].Text;
                            Stop.Start();
                            new Methods.Generate(FileName, FileHost, Sender as BackgroundWorker);
                        });
```

and using normal for loop

```
for (int Indices = 0; Indices < Details.Items.Count; Indices++)
                        {
                            FileName = Details.Items[Indices].SubItems[7].Text;

                                Thread Generating = new Thread(() => new Methods.Generate(FileName, FileHost, Sender as BackgroundWorker))
                            {
                                IsBackground = true
                            };

                            Generating.Start();
                            Generating.Join();
                        }
```

I want output to process Only 2 movie at a single time and no restriction for genre of that particular movie.

Example like Avengers Infinity War and Mission Impossible Fallout at first to generate. After either of Avengers Infinity War or Mission Impossible Fallout completes uploading its media information i want to start third one Toy Story 4 and so on. (2 at current time and when 1 finish add another 1)

Generate Method :

```
    class Generate
    {
        public Generate(string FileName, string FileHost, BackgroundWorker BW)
        {
            Random Rand = new Random();

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            BW.ReportProgress(Rand.Next(0, 40), FileHost + " " + new FileInfo(FileName).Name);


            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            BW.ReportProgress(Rand.Next(40, 70), FileHost + " " + new FileInfo(FileName).Name);


            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            BW.ReportProgress(Rand.Next(70, 100), FileHost + " " + new FileInfo(FileName).Name);
}
}
```

Additional :

```
private void BackgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.UserState.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Look up TPL Dataflow.

Comment: Using a `BackgroundWorker` defeats the purpose of using `Parallel.For`. To offload work to background threads you should use one way or the other. Mixing both is confusing to say the least. Also you still haven't included the code that does the actual work of processing the movies.

Comment: Please provide us with a [mcve]. If we had all of your code we could offer you a very simple way to achieve what you're after. You seem to have a lot of stuff going on for a very simple task. We can help if you help us.

Comment: I tried using for loop and it is doing it one by one and it is working perfectly. But i want to do multiple at same time and its huge code and unable to share it here. Can anyone add me on Skype (Skype ID: saurav.neo@live.com). So that i can provide more detail scenario and help me out to get multiple processing at same time. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the overload of [`Parallel.For`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for#System_Threading_Tasks_Parallel_For_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Threading_Tasks_ParallelOptions_System_Action_System_Int32__) that accepts a `ParallelOptions` argument. It allows configuring the degree of parallelism.

```
var options = new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 };
Parallel.For(0, Details.Items.Count, options, i =>
{
    FileName = Details.Items[i].SubItems[7].Text;
    Stop.Start();
    new Methods.Generate(FileName, FileHost, Sender as BackgroundWorker);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for comment. I tried using your code and it is only showing the 
Mission Impossible Fallout file not the Avengers Infinity War file.
Reading second file only.

Comment: The `Parallel.For` method runs your loop in 2 parallel threads. But I have no idea what's inside the loop. What `Stop.Start()` does, and why you need to cast the `Sender` variable as `BackgroundWorker`? There is probably much more code that you haven't shown to us.

Comment: Stopwatch Stop = new Stopwatch(); for stopwatch Stop.Start()  and sender as backgroundworker is for providing backgroundworker.reportprogress from Generate class.

Comment: Generate class has following : public Generate(string FileName, string FileHost, BackgroundWorker BW) { Random Rand = new Random(); Thread.Sleep(1000); BW.ReportProgress(Rand.Next(0, 40), new FileInfo(FileName).Name); }

Comment: @CoolDevil I suggest that you update your question by adding the `Generate` method. The comments are not suitable for posting code.

Comment: Done check it with additional information. 
e.UserState.ToString() provides the filename that is completed.

Answer (score 0):

```
var options = new ParallelOptions();
options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2;
Parallel.For(0, Details.Items.Count, options, i =>
            {
                FileName = Details.Items[i].SubItems[7].Text;
                Stop.Start();
                new Methods.Generate(FileName, FileHost, Sender as BackgroundWorker);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

i removed paralle.for and now m using.. for loop and it is working perfectly fine except i am able to do one by one processing only. That will also work.

```
for (int Indices = 0; Indices < Details.Items.Count; Indices++)
                        {
                            FileName = Details.Items[Indices].SubItems[7].Text;

                            Stop.Start();

                                Thread Generating = new Thread(() => new Methods.Generate(FileName, FileHost, Sender as BackgroundWorker))
                            {
                                IsBackground = true
                            };

                            Generating.Start();
                            Generating.Join();
                        }
```